# I want to place background image where "image url" is not present

Tags: android, json, image, listview

I want to place background image where "image url" is not present .

I am not getting background image where image url is not present . why it is not appearing ?

Please see in the image one image url is not present in the json where it should be replace with "bc.jpeg" which i have placed in drawable folder.

But it is not coming why it is not showing ?

[image: image not present]

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String url = "http://qzrbzpztcd.localtunnel.me/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=10&page=1&sort_col=average_ratings";
    // Movies json url
    //private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_url"));
                                movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                                //movie.setAddress(obj.getString("address"));
                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
                                // Genre is json array
                                /*JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

list row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Restaurant name  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/area"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cuisine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Genre -->
   <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />-->
<!--
    &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Customlist Adapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView average_ratings = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.average_ratings);
        TextView address=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        TextView cuisine =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuisine);
        //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        //thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        if (m.getThumbnailUrl().compareTo("")!=0)
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        else{
        thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);
        }


        // title
        name.setText(m.getName());

        // rating
        average_ratings.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getAverage_ratings()));
        address.setText("Area: " + String.valueOf(m.getAddress()));
        cuisine.setText("Cusine: " + String.valueOf(m.getCuisine()));
        /*// genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));*/

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Movie.java

```
public class Movie {
    private String name, thumbnailUrl;
    //private int year;
    private String average_ratings,area,cuisine,address;
//  private ArrayList<String> genre;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String average_ratings,String area,String cuisine,String address
            ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        //this.year = year;
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
        this.area=area;
        this.cuisine=cuisine;
this.address=address;
        //this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /*public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }*/

    /*public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }*/

    public String getAverage_ratings() {
        return average_ratings;
    }

    public void setAverage_ratings(String average_ratings) {
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }
    /*public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
*/
}
```

Comment: give your json code

Comment: did not get . Could you please tell me where i  have to change in the code

Comment: "Please see in the image one image url is not present in the json where it should be replace with "bc.jpeg" which i have placed in drawable folder." i am confused that is your image in drawable or in json data

Comment: images are coming via json . But where image url is not present i want to replace with image url (where null) which i have placed in drawable folder .

Comment: You should use an image library like UniversalImageLoader or Picasso, they will handle stuff like that for you.

Comment: @anti_gone i have used volley library

Comment: Volley gets HTTP string data, it isn't really made to load images like Picasso, for example.

Answer (score 1):

To display a placeholder while the image is loading, use:

```
thumbNail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.your_placeholder);
```

To display an image error if the image doesn`t load for any error, use:

```
thumbNail.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.your_error);
```

What about use Glide?

"Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface."

its use is too easy.

Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);

Using this, Glide handle everything to you.

Comment: post the implementation you did, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the URL is null or empty

```
if TextUtils.isEmpty(m.getThumbnailUrl())
```

You your JSON doesn't have the ability to get the key for the URL, then I don't think `obj.getString("image_url")` returns an empty string. `obj.getOptString("image_url")` might (if you are using the JSON API with that method)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's almost impossible to give any more of an answer without you editing the question to show your JSON

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);`

You can use the default and error method for it

```
else {
  thumbNail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
  thumbNail.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) instead of setImageResource something like thumbNail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);

Comment: So that means that m.getThumbnailUrl() could be "null" and it is going inside the if condition. May be you can put some logs and check if it is going inside the if condtition